# Многострочный вывод ячейки в JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, что никак не могу заставить исходниками из интернета, которые, как говорят их авторы "работают", заставить вывод в таблице JTable сделать многострочным.

Взял к примеру код отсюда: http://www.sql.ru/forum/707518/mnogostrochnyy-renderer-v-jtable

Добавляю данные в таблицу через DefaultTableModel.

Применяю исходник, как

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new TextAreaRenderer());
```

Для теста можно взять таблицу отсюда: http://ru.jakeroid.com/primeryi-ispolzovaniya-jtable.html .

Прошу помощи, так как перерыл уже все и вывод многострочным так сделать и не получилось.

[image: example]

Comment: это вообще возможно, сделать вывод многострочным в JTable ?

Comment: поменяйте в `table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new TextAreaRenderer());` на `Object.class`, если используете `DefaultTableModel` или конструктор с массивами

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ, вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

`JTable` определяет используемый рендерер по-умолчанию не по реальному классу объекта в ячейке, а по возвращаемому значению [`TableModel.getColumnClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass-int-). `DefaultTableModel.getColumnClass` всегда возвращает `Object.class`, поэтому назначенный для строк рендерер не используется.

Для решения проблемы можно назначить ваш рендерер для `Object.class`, переопределить `getColumnClass` в модели или задать рендерер столбцу через [`TableColumn.setCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setCellRenderer-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-):

```
// аргумент getColumn - номер колонки в порядке отображения
table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).setCellRenderer( new TextAreaRenderer() );
```